# Eliminar todos los tonos de un color de bitmap c#

Tags: c#, imagen, ocr

Hola estoy tratando de eliminar todos los tonos de anaranjado de una imagen guardada en un bitmap, necesito hacer OCR en la imagen con tesseract y el color anaranjado del documento scaneado parece entorpecer el proceso produciendo errores en el texto, He probado quitando el color naranja yo con photoshop, haciendo el OCR y funciona a la perfeccion, el problema principal es que los pixeles no son todos de un mismo color, son color naranja pero en diferentes tonalidades

```
Bitmap modificar = new Bitmap("imagenamodificar.png");
            for (int ycount2 = 0; ycount2 < modificar.Height; ycount2++)
            {
                for (int xcount2 = 0; xcount2 < modificar.Width; xcount2++)
                {
                    if (modificar.GetPixel(xcount2, ycount2) == Color.Orange)
                    {
                        modificar.SetPixel(xcount2, ycount2, Color.White);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Este codigo no hace absolutamente nada , la imagen queda identica.

Luego se me ocurrio comparar con el pixel(0,0) ya que siempre es del color que deseo eliminar.

```
Bitmap modificar = new Bitmap("imagenamodificar.png");
            for (int ycount2 = 0; ycount2 < modificar.Height; ycount2++)
            {
                for (int xcount2 = 1; xcount2 < modificar.Width; xcount2++)
                {
                    if (modificar.GetPixel(xcount2, ycount2) == modificar.GetPixel(0,0))
                    {
                        modificar.SetPixel(xcount2, ycount2, Color.White);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Pero el problema es que solo elimina una pequeña parte , siguen quedando pixeles color naranja por que como ya he mencionado antes no todos los tonos de naranja son iguales, a alguien se le ocurre algo?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema esta en esta condición

```
if (modificar.GetPixel(xcount2, ycount2) == modificar.GetPixel(0,0))
```

Estas comparando con un color concreto, deberías comparar con un rango, deberías comparar con los tonos naranjas.

Podrias hacer algo asi:

```
Color colorNaranja = Color.FromArgb(255, 100, 0); //NARANJA
int nNaranja = colorNaranja.ToArgb();
Color colorNaranjaClaro = Color.FromArgb(255, 180, 0); //NARANJA CLARO
int nNaranjaClaro = colorNaranjaClaro.ToArgb();

Bitmap modificar = new Bitmap("imagenamodificar.png");
            for (int ycount2 = 0; ycount2 < modificar.Height; ycount2++)
            {
                for (int xcount2 = 1; xcount2 < modificar.Width; xcount2++)
                {
                   int n= modificar.GetPixel(xcount2, ycount2).ToArgb();
                    if ((n>nNaranja) && (n<nNaranjaClaro)) 
                    {
                        modificar.SetPixel(xcount2, ycount2, Color.White);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Espero te sirva.